# Are there any speed benefits when loading modules just before usage in CGI?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cgi

I'm building a web application using CGI in Python. Since the script `foo.py` needs to be loaded every time it's called at `mypage.com/foo.py` I'm looking for some ways to speed up the initialization.

When using a framework such as Django or web.py I always load the modules at the top of the file. Let's say I'm importing the function `func` and using it in my request handler:

```
from module import func
# ...
def request_handler(user_input):
    if user_input == 1:
        func()
```

In this case the framework will just call the `request_handler` when someone loads some page instead of loading the full python file. In CGI the script is loaded every time the URL is visited, that means `func` will be imported from `module` every time too. Since `func` won't be called always, because `user_input` may be a different value than `1` I opted to import it just when necessary, like this:

```
if user_input == 1:
    from module import func
    func()
```

Am I making a performance improvement or it's just the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are making a marginal speed improvement, provided that `module` would not be imported otherwise.